# What is the significance of Loki and Mobius eating green pie in the TVA?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In *Loki* Season 2, there's a scene where Loki and Mobius eat green pie in the TVA. This happens right after they try to get information from X-5 (Brad Wolfe) without success.

Why is the green pie important in this scene? Is it just for fun, or does it have a deeper meaning related to the story or characters?

Has this been explained by the producers or other authoritative sources?

Comment: It's described as "key lime pie". There is a theory that because key lime pie is actually NOT naturally green the idea is that it tends to make you unconciously aware that it's as fake as everything else about the TVA

Comment: Because they were hungry

Comment: Can you edit in *why* you think there is any specific meaning to it?

Comment: I think the reason is apparent: why would they eat something random in the middle of an important scene in the last season of the series? I think there might be an idea behind this happening. @Joachim

Comment: Same reason why in Pulp Fiction they talked about hamburgers.